# How to get top 10 category list in laravel eloquent query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

i have three table one is `category` table and another is `product` table and one more `product_to_category` table, and it has only `product_id` and `category_id` column.

Now i want to get top 10 categories with maximum number of product, with details of 10 products from each category.

What i wrote is

```
$result = ProductToCategory::groupBy('category_id')->with(['product',function($q){
  $q->take(10);
}])->orderBy('category_id)->take(10);
```

But this is not working.How to write this query properly
Can anyone please help. ty

**Model relations**

For Product model

```
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductToCategory::class);
    }
```

For Category model

```
 public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductToCategory::class);
    }
```

For ProductToCategory model

```
 public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

Comment: Is your tables named exactly like you mentioned above

Comment: yes, those are same and the model are also linked

Comment: @user7747472 you've just updated the answer with the relationships but these relationships do not make any sense. It looks like the classic one-to-many relationship, so you don't need to use `ProductToCategory` model and related table at all.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin no, here one product can be in many categories. That is why i added `productToCategory` table. Its like `manytomany ` relationship
So basically in my system of mine , one product for example `banana `can be in many category such as `seasional fruits, Fruits, healthy fruits` and so on. same way one category can have many products , for example `healthy fruit` can have `banana, apple, pinaapple`
Like that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way would be using a raw SQL query because you can't filter products by using eager loading constraint.

But if you want an Eloquent solution anyway, define the relationships:

In the `Product` model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_to_category');
}
```

And in the `Category` model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_to_category');
}
```

Then you'll have two options, both have their pros and cons:

**1.** This code will execute just 2 queries but will use more memory. You could get top ten categories with their products:

```
$categories = Category::withCount('products')->latest('products_count')->take(10)->with('products')->get();
```

And then keep only first ten products:

```
$categories->transform(function($category) {
    $topProducts = $category->products->take(10);
    unset($category->products);
    $category->products = $topProducts;
    return $category;
});
```

**2.** This solution will create 12 queries but will save the memory:

```
$categories = Category::withCount('products')->latest('products_count')->take(10)->get();
$categories->transform(function($category) {
    $category->products = Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) use($category) {
        $q->where('id', $category->id);
    })
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
    return $category;
});
```

Comment: This worked, i took your 2nd option since you said it consume less memory.

Comment: Hey @Alexey Mezeni, Can you explain please how the first version will take more memory? though I like the first version as it is lesser and easy to understand.

Comment: @HaiderAli it will load the top 10 categories with all products for these ten categories into the memory instead of loading top 10 categories with just 10 products for each category. Then it will just remove redundant loaded products.

Comment: @HaiderAli it depends. If you're looking for the best performance solution, go for a raw SQL. I would use Eloquent anyway to keep the app maintainable.

Comment: @HaiderAli sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166181/discussion-between-haider-ali-and-alexey-mezenin).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the DB facade version:

```
$tenPopularTags = DB::table('product_to_category')
                      ->join('category', 'product_to_category.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(product_to_category.category_id) as repetition, question_tag.tag_id'))
                     ->groupBy('product_to_category.category_id')
                     ->orderBy('repetition', 'desc')->take(10)
                     ->get();
```

However I like @Alexey Mezenin way of doing it. Because that is the cleaner way have customized it a bit:

```
$tenCategories = Category::withCount('products')->orderBy('questions_count', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
```

Have used both in my project blog with post and categories relationship and it works!

Comment: This will load all categories and all products into the memory.

Comment: Let me check it on my side, I am going to do it in my project.

Comment: This giving me result but its returning only one product, but i want to return 10 product for each category . is it possible?

Comment: I change your code base little more `$categories = Category::with(['products',function($q){
$q->take(10);
}]->with('category')
                ->get()
                ->sortByDesc(function($category){
                    return $category->products->count();
                })->take(10);`
This giving error saying `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: @user7747472 even if you'll fix this code, it will give you just 10 products total and not 10 products per each category.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin oh okay,let me run the code you shared